# Fremlin - Exercise 112Y(e) - Measure of the counting set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(E_n)_n$ be a sequence of sets in $\Sigma$. Define the following sets:
> \begin{equation}
> H^{n_0}_k:= \{x \in X: \text{card}(\{n \leq n_0: x \in E_n\})\geq k \} \\
> H^{+\infty}_k:= \{x \in X: \text{card}(\{n \in \Bbb N: x \in E_n\})\geq k \}
> \end{equation}
> i.e. $H^{n_0}_k$ contains those $x\in X$ that are contained in at least $k$ sets among the first $n_0+1$ sets of $(E_n)_n$ and $H^{+\infty}_k$ contains those $x \in X$ that are contained in at least $k$ sets among all the sets of $(E_n)_n$.
> Prove that:
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \mu (H^{+\infty}_k) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\mu(E_k)
> \end{equation}

So far I have been able to prove that for every choice of $n_0 \in \Bbb N$:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n_0+1}\mu(H^{n_0}_k) = \sum_{n=0}^{n_0}\mu(E_n)
\end{equation}
but I couldn't go further than that. I tried proving that $\lim_{n_0 \to +\infty}\mu(H^{n_0}_k) = H^{+\infty}_k$ for every choice of $k \geq 1$ without any success.

I would appreciate any hint on how to proceed.

Comment: You mean to say that they are contained in at least $k$ sets, right?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

I think that since you have two indices to consider, you might have to be more careful when taking a limit. You can definitely say that $\lim_{n_0 \to +\infty}\mu(H^{n_0}_k) = H^{+\infty}_k$, since $\mathbf{1}_{H_k^n}$ is an increasing function with respect to $n$ and $\mathbf{1}_{H_k^n} \to \mathbf{1}_{H_k^\infty}$ pointwise for all $k$.

I think you should note that $H_k^n=\emptyset$ when $n>k+1$. So in fact the left Hand side that you wrote is actually $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(H^{n_0}_k) $. You still have to show why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(H^{n_0}_k) \overset{n_0\to \infty}{\to} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(H^{\infty}_k)$.

I think a simpler idea would be to consider $h(x,n)=\mathbf{1}_{E_n}(x)$ in the product space $X\times \mathbb{N}$ with the product measure $\mu \times \nu$, where $\nu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

**Edit:**

If you can only use basic results in measure theory, you need to work harder. i.e., you can show that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu (H^{\infty}_k) \geq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(E_n) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu (H^{\infty}_k) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(E_n). $$

From what you already wrote, you can show that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{n_0}\mu(E_n) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(H^{\infty}_k), $$

since $H_k^\infty \supseteq H_k^{n}$ for all $n$. Since this is true for all $n_0$, this gives you one inequality.

You now have to show the other inequality. You can assume $\mu(E_n)<\infty$ for all $n$ and that $\sum \mu(E_n)<\infty$, otherwise there is nothing to show. Note that $H_{k+1}^\infty \subseteq H_k^\infty$ for all $k$.

Since we assumed $\sum \mu(E_n)<\infty$, we get that $\mu(E_n)\overset{n\to \infty}{\to} 0$. In particular, $\mu \big( \liminf E_n \big)=0$.

Since $\cup_{k=1}^\infty H_k^\infty = \cup_{n=0}^\infty E_n$, this shows that $\mu\big( \cap_{k=1}^\infty H_k^\infty \big)=0$. I think you could try to prove the remaining inequality from this.

Comment: I will certainly consider your first suggestion and see if that is what I needed, however I knew about your second suggestion but I do not see how it is different from what I wrote (I am moderately sure that my left hand side is correct in the last formula I wrote)

Comment: @MatteoMenghini I was editing my answer when I saw your comment, so I'm not sure after the change which suggestions you  mean.  If you meant that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(H^{n_0}_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n_0+1}\mu(H^{n_0}_k)$, I did just want to highlight that.

Comment: @Keen-amateur Yes, that was exactly it. Could you expand your last idea? I have never heard of the product measure so far.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini In that case, my comment might not be useful to you. I was suggesting to use Tonelli's theorem here. What book is this from again?

Comment: Fremlin - Volume 1 (it is an open source book)

Comment: Also, if I can show that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \mu(H_k^n) \to \mu(H_k^{+\infty})$ I might be able to show the equality between the two series (by contradiction e.g.) but I do not understand how would you go about using the characteristic functions.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini Are you familiar with some theorems on integration? Like the Monotone convergence theorem? Also, the integral of a characterstic function of a set, is the measure of that set.

Comment: @Keen-amateur Unfortunately the book has not introduced the integrals yet (it has only introduced measurable and measure spaces)