# Fremlin 112Y(e) - Sum of measure of counting sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve Exercise 112Y(e) from Fremlin's Measure Theory (Volume 1):

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(E_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\Sigma$. Define $H_k=\{x\in X:|\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x\in E_n\}|\geq k\}$. **The goal is to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(H_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(E_k)$.**

I proved that $H_k=\bigcup_{S\subset\mathbb{N},|S|=k}\bigcap_{i\in S}E_i$. Fremlin's hint is to first consider the case where only finitely many $E_k$ are non-empty. In this case one needs to prove $\sum_{k=1}^n\mu\left(\bigcup_{S\subset\{1,\ldots,n\},|S|=k}\bigcap_{i\in S}E_i\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(E_k)$. The infinitary case is then clear (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639755/fremlin-exercise-112ye-measure-of-the-counting-set)). I tried proving this formula by induction, using the inclusion-exclusion principle but that lead nowhere. It seems that I am missing some elementary set-theoretic manipulation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the required case when there are only finitely many sets $E_1,\dots, E_n$. Put $Y=\{0,1\}^n$
and for each $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)\in Y$ put $|y|=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$. Let $\chi:X\to Y$ be the diagonal product of the sequence $(\chi_{E_1},\dots,\chi_{E_k})$ of the characteristic maps, that is for each $x\in X$ each natural $k\le n$ the $k$th component of $\chi(x)$ equals $1$, if $x\in E_k$, and equals $0$, otherwise. Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(E_k)=\sum_{y\in Y}\mu(\chi^{-1}(y))|y|=  
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{y\in Y\,|y|\ge k}\mu(\chi^{-1}(y))=$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mu\left(\bigcup_{y\in Y\,|y|\ge k}\mu(\chi^{-1}(y))\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(H_k).$$